# what does "Configuration is valid for a viable prefix " means?

Tags: parsing, lr-grammar

I am learning LR(1) parsing from **THE DRAGON BOOK**. I am really confused with this sentence.

Formally we say that a configuration **[A –> u•v, a]** is valid for a viable prefix **α** if 
there is a rightmost derivation **S =>* βAw =>* βuvw** where **α = βu** and either **a** is the first 
symbol of **w** or **w** is **∂** and **a** is **$**.

I am not able to figure out how validation of a configuration for a viable prefix is **`useful`** .
What does it speak **`intutively`** and why it **`matters`** ???

Please help ....